# Redirect from old, non-html5Mode routes to new html5Mode routes in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to switch my Angular app to use html5Mode routing. But I also want to redirect requests to my old routes to my new ones. When I try this it doesn't work. Here's what I have:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/foo/browse', {
        templateUrl: '/app/foo-browse.html',
        controller: 'BrowseFoos'
    })
    .when('/foo/#/browse', {
        redirectTo: '/foo/browse'
    });

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

But when I enter the url in my browser like this `http://localhost/foo/#/browse` it gets encoded and not redirected properly (looking like this in the browser's url bar: `http://localhost/foo/#%2Fbrowse`)

Is there something special that I can do to fix this?

Comment: do you have html5 route enables? @programmer

Comment: Yes, I recently enabled it and now I want to still support old links that are out there pointing at my hash links.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a quick and dirty js redirect and calling it a day. I put this in my html>head tag:

```
<script>       
(function redirectOldCrustyHashBasedUrls() {
    'use strict';
    var href = window.location.href;
    if(href.indexOf('/my-app/#/') !== -1){
        href = href.replace('/my-app/#/', '/my-app/');
        window.location = href;
    }
})();
</script>
```